# Updating column of all rows in a table

Tags: mysql

I got a table with three columns.

```
+------+-------+------------+
| ID   | Title |  Date      |
+------+-------+------------+
|  1   | ABC   | 1460367600 |
+------+-------+------------+
```

Now I would like to update the `Date` of all rows. And for each row I want the `Date` to be reduced by 100. The first row would have the `Date = 1460367600.`

So the second row would have the `Date = 1460367500` and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using variable as follows:

```
SET @DIFF = 100;
SET @DATEVAL = 1460367700;

UPDATE TABLE YOUR_TABLE SET DATE = ( @DATEVAL := @DATEVAL - @DIFF );
```

Comment: `SET @Diff = 100;
`SET @DATEVAL = 1460367700;
`UPDATE appbox.Games SET Created = @DATEVAL:= @DATEVAL - @DIFF

Worked like a charm. Thank you sir.

Comment: @Reality-Torrent as a newbie at StackOverflow, It's a great pleasure for me to know that It helped you , Welcome :)